# Android: White screen while inflate

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an animal Quiz, by inflating my layout. The quiz is made of 1 image, 4 answers (for each page)

It works in some Android devices (eg:Samsung GS2) and I got a blank white screen on other devices (Galaxy note, GS3...) all running on 4.0.

I don't understand why.  Could you please give me some help ?

-------------- Layout part ---------------------

cat_quiz.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/home_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_quiz_score"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textSize="12dip"
                android:textStyle="normal" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/cat_quiz_item" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

cat_quiz_item.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.mycatfamily.widget.MyGallery
            android:id="@+id/photogallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_item_gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_quiz_button_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_quiz_button_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" >

            </TextView>


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_quiz_button_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_quiz_button_4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_photo_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/animal_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---------------- Adaptor Part ---------------------------

```
public class QuizAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity context;  
    public static int[] ids;
    public static int[] data;
    public static String[] name;
    public static String[] btn_1_name;
    public static String[] btn_2_name;
    public static String[] btn_3_name;
    public static String[] btn_4_name;
    public static int img_width=420;
    public static int img_height=300;
    public int score = 0; 
    public int answers=0;
private int cpt_popup=0;
public QuizAdaptor(Activity context) {   
        this.context = context; 
        } 
    public  class ViewHolder{   
        public TextView animal_id;
        public TextView text;    
        public ImageView image;     
        public TextView label_quiz_button_1;
        public TextView label_quiz_button_2;
        public TextView label_quiz_button_3;
        public TextView label_quiz_button_4;
        public MyGallery gallery;
    }   

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
        View view = null;
        if(convertView==null){  
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cat_quiz_item, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.animal_id=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.animal_id);
            viewHolder.text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label_photo_name);  
            viewHolder.image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_item_gallery);
            viewHolder.label_quiz_button_1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label_quiz_button_1);
            viewHolder.label_quiz_button_2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label_quiz_button_2);
            viewHolder.label_quiz_button_3=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label_quiz_button_3);
            viewHolder.label_quiz_button_4=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label_quiz_button_4);
            viewHolder.gallery = (MyGallery)view.findViewById(R.id.photogallery);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);          
        }  
        else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();    
        holder.animal_id.setText(String.valueOf(ids[position]));
        holder.text.setText(name[position]);
        final int stub_id=data[position];  
        holder.image.setImageResource(stub_id);
        holder.label_quiz_button_1.setText(btn_1_name[position]);
        holder.label_quiz_button_2.setText(btn_2_name[position]);
        holder.label_quiz_button_3.setText(btn_3_name[position]);
        holder.label_quiz_button_4.setText(btn_4_name[position]);
}
```

------------- Activity part   --------------------

```
 public class CatQuiz  extends Activity{
    public String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    public MyGallery galleryView;
    private TextView label_photo_name, animal_id;
    private TextView label_quiz_button_1,label_quiz_button_2,label_quiz_button_3,label_quiz_button_4;
    ArrayList<String> cat_arraylist;
    private int selectedImagePosition = 0;

    public String getRandomName(ArrayList<String> cat_array, String animal_name){
        int rd = (int) Math.round(Math.random()*(cat_array.size()-1));
        if((cat_array.get(rd)).equals(animal_name)){
            return getRandomName(cat_array,animal_name);
        }
        else{
            String rslt = cat_array.get(rd);
            return rslt;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cat_quiz);
        QuizAdaptor cs_gallery = new QuizAdaptor(this);
        animal_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.animal_id);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        animal_id.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        label_photo_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_photo_name);
        label_photo_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        label_quiz_button_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_quiz_button_1);
        label_quiz_button_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_quiz_button_2);
        label_quiz_button_3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_quiz_button_3);
        label_quiz_button_4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_quiz_button_4);

        CatBdd catBdd = new CatBdd(getApplicationContext());
        catBdd.open();
        List<Cat> animals = catBdd.getAllCatRandom();
        cat_arraylist = catBdd.getDistinctCatNameArray();
        final int size = 30;
        int i = 0;
        cs_gallery.data = new int[size];
        cs_gallery.name = new String[size];
        cs_gallery.ids = new int[size];
        cs_gallery.btn_1_name = new String[size];
        cs_gallery.btn_2_name = new String[size];
        cs_gallery.btn_3_name = new String[size];
        cs_gallery.btn_4_name = new String[size];
        String animal_img_name;
        String animal_name_btn1;
        String animal_name_btn2;
        String animal_name_btn3;
        String animal_name_btn4;

        while(i<size){
            String animal_name = animals.get(i).getName();
            int id_item = animals.get(i).getId();
            int rd = (int) Math.round(Math.random()*4);

            if(rd==1){
                animal_img_name = animals.get(i).getCat_images_a();
                animal_name_btn1 = animal_name;
                animal_name_btn2 = getRandomName(cat_arraylist, animal_name);
                animal_name_btn3 = getRandomName(cat_arraylist, animal_name);
                animal_name_btn4 =getRandomName(cat_arraylist, animal_name);

            }
            else if(rd==2){
                animal_img_name = animals.get(i).getCat_images_b();
                animal_name_btn1 = getRandomName(cat_arraylist, animal_name);
                animal_name_btn2 = animal_name;
                animal_name_btn3 = getRandomName(cat_arraylist, animal_name);
                animal_name_btn4 =getRandomName(cat_arraylist, animal_name);

            }
            else if(rd==3){
                animal_img_name = animals.get(i).getCat_images_c();
                animal_name_btn1 = getRandomName(cat_arraylist, animal_name);
                animal_name_btn2 = getRandomName(cat_arraylist, animal_name);
                animal_name_btn3 = animal_name;
                animal_name_btn4 =getRandomName(cat_arraylist, animal_name);
            }
            else {
                animal_img_name = animals.get(i).getCat_images_d();
                animal_name_btn1 = getRandomName(cat_arraylist, animal_name);
                animal_name_btn2 = getRandomName(cat_arraylist, animal_name);
                animal_name_btn3 = getRandomName(cat_arraylist, animal_name);
                animal_name_btn4 =animal_name;
            }
            cs_gallery.ids[i] = id_item;
            cs_gallery.name[i] = animal_name;
            cs_gallery.data[i] = Integer.valueOf(animal_img_name);
            cs_gallery.btn_1_name[i] = animal_name_btn1;
            cs_gallery.btn_2_name[i] = animal_name_btn2;
            cs_gallery.btn_3_name[i] = animal_name_btn3;
            cs_gallery.btn_4_name[i] = animal_name_btn4;
            i++;
        }
```